# Named Array Formula Not Returning Correct Result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am have a problem with a named formula in excel the contains an if statement and array formula.  The basic problem is that for the entire range the evaluation only returns the value of the first cell in the range.  Following with Evaluate Formula Everything works correctly until it should resolve down to the individual elements.

The problem is coming from a formula like:

```
=IF(TRUE,1*{1,2,3,4},0) w/(CRTL-SHIFT-ENTER)
```

Which works fine if I enter it as a normal array function, it returns to the four selected cells {1,2,3,4}

But if I named a named formula called FailingNamedFormula using the exact same formula as above and then when I go to use it in the following way:

```
=FailingNamedFormula   w/(CRTL-SHIFT-ENTER)
```

This is where everything breaks down instead of the 4 cells containing the values they should I get {1,1,1,1}.

The strange thing is if I go through the same exercise with the formula:

```
=IF(TRUE,1,0)*{1,2,3,4}    w/(CRTL-SHIFT-ENTER)
```

Both the normal version and the named version work fine.

In both cases of using the named formulas in the Evaluated Formula dialog, it shows the array {1,2,3,4} till the last step, but when it goes to pick out the correct element using the first formula always returns the first element of the list, while the second version does it correctly.

I just don't understand why the first formula doesn't work as a named formula.
That is the form I would like to use because it is much more computationally efficent.

Comment: Very odd indeed.  If you want a workaround, you can use `INDEX(FailingNamedFormula, 2)` or whatever index, and it will return correctly... **or** even odder, you can use `=INDEX(FailingNamedFormula, COLUMN(1:1))` as an array formula and it will get you all 4 again for the formula associated with the first form.  You can also get them all with `INDEX(FailingNamedFormula, 1, )` as an array formula.

Comment: With regards, to selecting adjacent sells I have and that is where you see issue, in the case that fails instead of getting the four different values I just get  the first value in all four cells.

As for the other work arounds the actual use case is more complicated but i need to return all the results at the same time where each array is actually 36 cells big and it is done maybe in 1000 rows.  I think that the index version would end up calculating the formula 36 times, and would be computationally inefficent.